# Flash CC convert to HTML5 canvas project batch

Tags: flash, html5

How can I batch convert Flash movies to HTML5 canvas projects (and publish them)?

Using Flash CC 2015

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=convert+flash+to+htmlt5) are one of the many ways.

Comment: @Ramhound I know how to do it by hand.  I want to do it in batch.  All of those links just cover how to do it manually.

Comment: Given that Flash is closed source proprietary format.  You are limited to the tools Adobe provides.  There might not be a batch tool for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622499/can-we-export-from-flash-to-createjs-from-the-command-line
Looks like it's possible using jsfl scripting.  This question was probably better suited for Stackoverflow

I went and wrote a jsfl script to convert and extract sounds in batch: https://gist.github.com/jhiswin/58928a237f8a7ebd2f69

Answer (score 1):

Google have got a product called [Swiffy](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en) that converts SWF files to HTML5. I haven't used it myself so I can't comment on it's effectiveness. It may be possible to use the API to create a batch processor.

Stack Overflow has a [google-swiffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-swiffy) tag.

Comment: I've actually already used Swiffy pretty extensively for a large batch of conversions, and it is very effective (and efficient).  Only problems are that it is closed source and difficult to modify/improve (bugs and limitations), and does not support streaming audio (among other things).

Comment: I've basically had to make a lot of dirty hacks to get it to do what I need.  It really would be nice if Google/Apple could open at least part of it, so I can fix the bugs or extend it to be more useful.

Comment: One big thing is that Adobe HTML5 canvas output supports streaming and produces reasonably good/modifiable output.  I've done some conversions to SVG SMIL that also sorta works, but it's lacking in performance, larger, buggier, harder to manipulate, and SMIL is due for deprecation.

Comment: It might be close-sourced due to the licensing issues that @ramhound alluded to. I have to admit I thought it was open-source.